# Using data from API inside javascript

Tags: javascript, string, api

i am using northwind api. Some products i get from api have ' in their name and its a problem because i wanna use it inside of function... I wanna have function buy that sends cost, name of product and quantity per unit, but when I call function i get inside of html

[image]

Instead of

`<button onclick='buy(4,"Chef Anton's Cajun Seasoning",22.0000)'>Buy</button>`

I tried using single quotes, double quotes, switched between, tried with \' and \" and different variation of ' and " , but nothing seams to work... Here is part of line of code that is troubling me

```
<button onclick ='buy(" + products.value[j].ProductID + ",'" 
+ (products.value[j].ProductName)+"',"+ products.value.UnitPrice +")'>Buy</button></div></div>"
```

also Northwind api I am usin is

`https://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products?$format=json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use HTML5 [`data-*` custom attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-data-*) to pass arbitrary data to event handler.

```
'<button data-product-id="' + products.value[j].ProductID '+" data-product-name="' + products.value[j].ProductName'+" data-unit-price="' + products.value.UnitPrice'+" onclick="wrapperBuy(this)">Buy</button>'
```

which can later, be fetched using [`Element.dataset` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset)

```js
function wrapperBuy(element) {
  var productId = element.dataset.productId,
    productName = element.dataset.productName,
    unitPrice = element.dataset.unitPrice;

  console.log(productId, productName, unitPrice);

  //You can invoke the original buy method
  //buy(productId, productName, unitPrice)
}
```

```html
<button data-product-id="4" data-product-name="Chef Anton's Cajun Seasoning" data-unit-price="2200" onclick="wrapperBuy(this)">Buy</button>
```

---

Additionally, I would strong recommend you to use unobtrusive event handlers i.e. `addEventListener()`

Comment: Thanks this did the trick for me... And I'll check out event listeners haven't worked with them yet...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```html
<button onclick ="buy(\'' + products.value[j].ProductID + '\',\'' + (products.value[j].ProductName) + '\',\'' + products.value.UnitPrice + '\')">Buy</button>
```